# how to remove final "dot" from directory name

Tags: bash, batch-rename

A program messed up my directory putting a dot "." on the end of some file and directory names. What is the easiest way to remove them?

I have thought of removing the last character but not all the files/dirs have a dot on the end. Also removing all the dots is a problem, this will make the extension useless.

What I need is a rename to change `name.of.the.file.ext.` to `name.of.the.file.ext` and `name.of.the.dir.` to `name.of.the.dir`

Thanks!

Comment: just write a script that scans the file names and checks for trailing dots, then discards them if necessary. you chould use the ´mv´ command to rename the files/directories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go over the files with the dot at the end, rename each if possible (i.e. the target file does not exist).

```
for file in *. ; do
    [[ -e ${file%.} ]] || mv "$file" "${file%.}"
done
echo Not renamed: *.
```

Comment: If the user has to descend into subdirectories: `shopt -s globstar; for file in **/*.; ...` . Also, why the `-e` test? Will `*.` return non-existing files?

Comment: @glennjackman: No, it tests the target in order not to overwrite it.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a `rename` utility on your machine that will let you do

```
rename 's/\.$//' *.
```

Check `man rename`