# linux mc extension command with DOT at the end

Tags: linux, xargs, mc

I need to cut some first characters from file name in current mc panel and create hard link in pasive mc panel with this name. Example:

```
ls 001-a\ b.flac | cut -c 5- | xargs -0 -I{} echo ln %p %D/{}
```

I get expectet result:

```
ln 001-a b.flac /srv/Music/a b.flac
```

But, without echo:

```
ls 001-a\ b.flac | cut -c 5- | xargs -0 -I{} ln %p %D/{}
```

I get result:

```
ln 001-a b.flac /srv/Music/a b.flac.
```

With DOT at the end of file name in pasive panel

I've found similar question [how to remove final “dot” from directory name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460511/how-to-remove-final-dot-from-directory-name). But how can I avoid this DOT at the end of file name in mc extension command?

PS
problem xpression in mc extension file:

```
regex/i/\.flac
Open=ls %p | cut -c 5- | xargs -0 -I{} ln %p %D/{}
```

ADDED SOLUTION ?

how make playlists with hard links and refactory names of songs in it I found in ["How can i pass all arguments with xargs in middle of command in linux"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639206/how-can-i-pass-all-arguments-with-xargs-in-middle-of-command-in-linux?rq=1)

```
ln %p %D/"`ls %p | cut -c 5- `"
```

It works in mc envirounment only

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using find/sed to modify the name?

```
find . -name "001-a b.flac" -maxdepth 0 -print0 | sed 's/001-//g' | xargs -0 -I{} ln %p %D/{}
```

Then you could of course make sed more generic:

```
sed 's/[[:digit:]]\+-//g'
```

I'm not sure what "mc" is, so my answer is probably not exactly what you need.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

how make playlists with hard links and refactory names of songs in it I found in ["How can i pass all arguments with xargs in middle of command in linux"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639206/how-can-i-pass-all-arguments-with-xargs-in-middle-of-command-in-linux?rq=1)

```
ln %p %D/"`ls %p | cut -c 5- `"
```

It works in mc envirounment only

user1855805